# Create IF statement from a variable size array

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a lnprior function which should change according to the parameters I want to fit while some are kept fixed. Let's say I have

```
p0 = [1,20]
p1 = [[0,2],[10,30]]
```

Basically I have:

```
a, b = p0
a_, b_ = p1
if (a_[0] < a < a_[1]) and (b_[0] < b < b_[1]):
```

However, `p0` and `p1` can have a changing dimension as for instance

```
p0 = [1,20, 300]
p1 = [[0,2],[10,30],[200, 400]]
```

In that case the IF condition should be:

```
a, b, c = p0
a_, b_, c_ = p1
if (a_[0] < a < a_[1]) and (b_[0] < b < b_[1]) and (c_[0] < c < c_[1])
```

Is there a way to automatically create the IF statement according to the size of `p0` (in my real code `p0` is a dictionary, which might be easier to manipulate)?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Selcuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65677038/21945), but a bit more readable, I think:

```
all(low < value < high for value, (low, high) in zip(p0, p1))
```

This zips the lists to associate the value with its upper and lower bounds, then iterates over all pairs and tests whether `value` is between the `low` and `high` values. `all()` ensures that all values are within their respective bounds.

```
>>> p0 = [1, 20, 300]
>>> p1 = [[0, 2], [10, 30], [200, 400]]
>>> all(low < value < high for value, (low, high) in zip(p0, p1))
True

>>> p0 = [1, 10, 300]
>>> all(low < value < high for value, (low, high) in zip(p0, p1))
False
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reasons I always have True, even if p0 = [1, 10, 300]

Comment: It works as shown above. I have also tried on 2.7 (just in case) and it works without modification. Did you perhaps change `<` to `<=`? Or some other change?

Comment: no change, also tried on 2.7 and the same.```

Comment: ```In [2021]: p0 = [1, 10, 300]                                                                              

In [2022]: if all(low < value < high for value, (low, high) in zip(p0, p1)):print('ok')                   
ok```

Comment: Ok, it's a ipython behavior then, your syntax works with python, not with ipython

Comment: OK. Instead of using the list comprehension fix try a generator expression, i.e. instead of wrapping the inner expression passed to `all()` with `[....]` use `(...)`

Comment: My code (GUI) uses python so your syntax should work. I however do some code test in ipython

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Don't unpack `p0` and `p1` manually but use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) with [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) instead:

```
if all(p1[i][0] < p0[i] < p1[i][1] for i in range(len(p0))):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found why I have always True, I have to insert [] in all():

```
all([low < value < high for value, (low, high) in zip(p0, p1)])
```

I'll test with the real code now

Comment: This won't make any difference to the result. It is adding an unnecessary list comprehension which will just slow things down an potentially use more memory for long lists.

Comment: You most likely used a wrong `p1` value in your original test. This change won't affect the result.